# How do I fix my BIOS after a failed update?

Tags: bios

I have a Dell Vostro 3400 (laptop).  I just tried updating the BIOS on it, but it failed.  It went to a black screen with fan screaming.  I had to unplug the machine and remove the battery to turn it off.  When I turn it on, I just get a black screen and a few beeps.

Answer (score 3):

I had to download the BIOS executable from the Dell Vostro 3400 on another computer.  (https://support.dell.com)

I followed these commands.

1. Run `3400_A01.exe /writehdrfile`
2. Rename the file as `winery40.hdr` (Other models may need to be renamed differently.  The BIOS program for Dell is called Winery.)
3. Run `3400_A01.exe /writeromfile`
4. Copy the `winery*.hdr` and `.rom` files to a USB drive.
5. Insert the USB drive into the dead laptop's USB port.
6. Hold down the `End` key, and then connect the power.  (Yes, the `End` key.  I was quite surprised to see this actually work.)
7. The dead laptop reads the USB drive (check for blinking lights).
8. A BIOS update screen will be displayed.  Select `Proceed with Update.`
9. Allow the update to finish.
10. Press `Esc` to turn off the computer.
11. Turn on the computer.

Yee-haw!